# React App works locally but getting Unexpected Token error in CodePen

Tags: javascript, reactjs, babeljs, codepen

I am working through a coding test for a job interview which is using codepen as the environment. I worked locally for past day and after copy pasting code into codepen I am getting Unexpected Token error at the `render( <App />, document.getElementById('root')).` I have triple checked to ensure it's not just a closed curly brace or something.

In my inspection tool under verbose (chrome) I am getting 25 [Violation] Added non-passive event listener to a scroll-blocking  event. Consider marking event handler as 'passive' to make the page more responsive. See " They are for mouse-wheel events and on-touch etc which are not part of the application. Other sources say this is not a cause for concern. I'm sort of at a loss and hoping someone could provide some insight. Is codepen just not suitable for managing a reasonably complex React application which manages multiple states?

Chrome inspector suggests adding passive to event listeners, I have two assigned to a particular onChange event but have tried commenting out to see if it would solve the issue to no avail. How would I add this passive argument to a event listener via HTML. Only examples I've seen use it as such.

```
document.addEventListener('touchstart', onTouchStart, {passive: true})
```

Below is my onChange handler

```js
    <input
            ref={donationAmountRef}
            className="donation-input"
            name="dollar-input"
            type="text"
            placeholder="$"
            // onChange={(errorHandler, (e) => onChangeHandler(e))}
            onChange={(e) => {
              errorHandler();
              onChangeHandler(e);
            }}
          ></input>
```

Here is a picture of expected result. [image: expected output]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ignore the `[Violation]` for now. Your problem is the `Unexpected token`, which suggests a syntax error preventing your code from compiling at all.

Something's wrong with your `Button`. If you say this is working locally then there's no way this is the same code that you're running.

```
const Button = (props) => {

  const onClickHandler = () => {
 
    const onClickHandler = () => {
    props.setUserState({
      ...props.userState,
      isDonating: true,
    });
    
  };

  return (
    <div className="button" onClick={onClickHandler}>
      <p>Give Now!</p>
    </div>
  );
};
```

There are 4 opening curly braces and 3 closing braces. There's your syntax error, and the cause of the `Unexpected token`.

---

The `Button` component doesn't return anything - the only thing within it is `onClickHandler`. (And, inexplicably, `onClickHandler` contains another `onClickHandler`.)

I'm going to assume that something went wrong while copying your code into CodePen.

Comment: Thank you! that was definitely a copy paste gone wrong but still havent got it working. Guess I need to take another careful look at all components.

Comment: Really embarassed. I wish I could just delete this question but I marked as correct as you did answer. The 2nd issue was I had to reimport jQuery for some reason.

Comment: @stephenbarter jQuery??? OK well best of luck with the interview.